# The order when BroadcastReceiver starts a Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I find that when a ***BroadcastReceiver*** starts a ***Service*** in ***onReceive***() method, the return of ***onReceive***()  will happen before the ***onCreate***() of the Service being invoked.  Why does this happen in this order?

The example code is below: `BroradcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()` method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("=====Receiver=======","===== onReceive starts====");  // (1)                    
    intent.setClass(context, AService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
    Log.i("=====Receiver=======","===== onReceive ends====");    // (2)
}
```

`Service`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
public void onCreate(){                      
    Log.i("=======Service========", "========OnCreate()=== ");  //(3)            
    // some logic here                
}
```

The log order is (1)(2)(3)，not (1)(3)(2).

Could anybody help explain it?

Answer (score 3):

The service has its own thread, so I would guess it doesn't get to run until the thread executing `onReceive` yields. It could also be that startService posts an intent, but again it doesn't get handled until `onReceive` returns. I don't know the actual implementation, but I do know that startService is an asynchronous call, so you shouldn't be depending on the order of execution rrlated to onReceive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.And I think posting an intent is more reasonable than "service has its own thread". Because I find that no new thread  created when the service starts. But I am not certain about the details of startService().
Thanks again anyway.